# Do newly added answers wipe out comments in progress?

Tags: bug, comment

I've recently had a few comments I was in the process of typing out wiped out when a new answer was posted to the question.  I don't remember this happening before, but I don't recall if the conditions existed for it to happen before.  It's difficult to set up the conditions for reproduction and testing, so:

- Has anyone else noticed this?
- Is this a new behavior?  Is it intentional?
- Is it possibly browser-sensitive?

This behavior has survived a reboot, incidentally.

Comment: Is the Comment "wiped out" when you refresh the page, to see the new Answer?  I'm accustomed to seeing a notification on the page that a new Answer has been added, without seeing such a post (unless I click the notification or otherwise refresh the page).

Comment: @hardmath: As far as I can tell, yes.  I've refreshed the page hoping to see my partial comment, but no dice. ¶ Yes, until recently, I always just got a "click here to refresh," but now the page just reloads with the new answer and wipes out my comment.

Comment: This sounds so so irritating! I hope this is a side effect of some recent change to the site software. If that the case it needs to be fixed.